# Apache NiFi Text Replacement

Tags: apache-nifi

what's the best way to replace strings within the [] (including the brackets) with values from attributes?

{
  "VoiceMessageTemplateEnglish" : "Hello, this is [LocationName] calling to confirm an appointment for [Name] on [AppointmentDate] at [AppointmentTime] with [Name]. Please press 1 To confirm, Press 2 To Cancel",
}

I tried using ExecuteScript processor with JS but did not have any luck.

Thanks!

Comment: you want replace all elements present inside the [] to be same attribute or different attributes?

Comment: The replacement values would be different for each element within [].

Comment: Replacement isn't a valid way to do your requirment.

Comment: All json rows should have LocationName,Name,AppointmentDate present in the [] right?

Comment: That’s correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using JS to solve the problem:

thanks @daggett for pointing me in the right direction

var flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) {

```
var lclAppointmentDate = flowFile.getAttribute("AppointmentDate");
var lclAppointmentStartTime = flowFile.getAttribute("AppointmentStartTime");
var lclName = flowFile.getAttribute("Name");
var lclVoiceMailTemplate = flowFile.getAttribute("VoiceMailTemplate");



if (lclVoiceMailTemplate != null){
    lclVoiceMailTemplate  = lclVoiceMailTemplate
                       .replace('[Name]', lclName)
                       .replace('[AppointmentDate]', lclAppointmentDate)
                       .replace('[AppointmentTime]', lclAppointmentStartTime);
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "FinalVoiceMailTemplate", lclVoiceMailTemplate);
}
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
session.commit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

processor `ExecuteGroovyScript` in nifi  1.5.0

```groovy
def ff = session.get()
if(!ff)return

def attr = ff.getAttributes()
def text = ff.read().getText("UTF-8")
text = text.replaceAll( /\[(\w+)\]/ ) {  attr[it[1]] ?: "noValue" }

ff.write("UTF-8", text)

REL_SUCCESS << ff
```

Comment: Thanks @daggett. I’ll give your recommendation a try this morning.